# Get logged in UserId in Blazor 6 Wasm controller

Tags: asp.net-identity, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Wasm app under .Net 6 (upgraded from .Net Core). I added default Identity from the Blazor Train video with Chris Sainty which now appears to work. I didn't want to use the Blazor 6 template & Duende.

But I can't get the UserId (not the email) within a controller.

There are several Stack Overflow questions about this but not a clear answer for Blazor 6.
In the controller, once logged in:

```
User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
```

returns null, also adding a test component to display the user Id also shows null for the user Id

```
if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        _authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
        _claims = user.Claims;
        _userId = $"User Id: {user.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value}";
    }
```

I see various statements about HttpContext not being available in Wasm controller, and userManager also not being available.  I've tried both with the same result.

Any guidance?

Comment: I cannot help you, but want you to know that I have NO LUCK asking about Core 6 and Blazor WASM and Authentication with Duende.  I have asked about the <AuthorizeView Roles="Admin"> not working on the blazor pages.  I get no replies. 
 I can see the User and Roles in the SQL-DB but for some reason Blazor page does not "see" the logged-in user's role.  There must be some secret way of plumbing all the pieces together in Core 6 DIFFERENT from previous CORE's. I feel your pain, brother. ☺  I need to see both SERVER and CLIENT Program.cs files where this works. Thanks.

Comment: I spent a lot of time on this and compromised.  In my Controllers I can use  userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) once a user is logged in.  I add the userId as a claim in my LoginController using await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginModel.Email));   So I can do what I need so far.  I also coudln't use scaffolding for the Wasm solution so I added my own Blazor pages based on the normal scaffolded Identity UI.  Does the trick.  I haven't used the roles yet.

Comment: @Craig...Thank you for your reply.  I actually found out that I was missing a sentence in the SERVER>Program.cs and that got the roles working.  I work alone at my computer and can use SqlServer queries to add roles and users "manually" for now.  My code is a little different from yours. I do have some helpful code snippets that may assist you.  If you need some help, ask me via Comments on this post.  I am working on getting the functionality to have "Admin" (role) CRUD users (employees) and now I know I can do it.  Thx.  John D.